# Ionic 2 with primeng style is not loading

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, styles, primeng

I am currently working with the p-datatable and I can correctly use it. The big problem is that the style is not loading in. The p-dataTable itself is working correctly , only the styles are not. I followed the steps on the getting started page on the site of primeng but still nothing from the styling works. Below is an image of my datatable, I should be using the standard one.

The datatable:
[image]

html:

```
<p-dataTable [value]="reports" [responsive]="false">
    <p-column field="_id" header="ID"></p-column>
    <p-column field="reportJSON.datamodel[0].data" header="SUBMITTED BY"></p-column>
    <p-column field="reportJSON.type" header="REPORT TYPE"></p-column>
    <p-column field="reportJSON.revision" header="REVISION"></p-column>
    <p-column header="STATE">
      <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-report="rowData">
        <button [ngClass]="{'final' : report.reportJSON.finalVersion===true, 'draft' : report.reportJSON.finalVersion===false}" ion-button round>{{report.reportJSON.finalVersion ? 'FINAL' : 'DRAFT'}}</button>
      </ng-template>
    </p-column>
    <p-column field="reportJSON.lastEditDate.date" header="DATE"></p-column>
  </p-dataTable>
```

angular-cli.json:
[image]

package.json:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by adding the maps of the style to the assets/css map and refer to there in the index.html file

Comment: Are you able to use primeng and all of its features in ionic?

Comment: Yes you can use it and all of its features @Ari

Comment: Can you please share any tips on how to do so? I haven't been able to do it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Config CSS in angular.json like this:

```
"styles": [
            "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
            "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css",
            "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
          {
            "input": "src/theme/variables.scss" 
          },
          {
            "input": "src/global.scss"
          }
        ]
```